# Is there a way to list all files in a S3 bucket between two dates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to fetch all files between two given dates using the S3 API called s3ap but I am not getting correct syntax for the same.

When I tried for all files after a given date I am able to do that by using below mentioned command:

```
aws s3api list-objects --profile flashtalking --bucket bucket-name --query "Contents[?LastModified >= '$last_modificaion_date']"
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the above query slightly and I was able to get it working.

Hope this helps!

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-128:~$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket s3-knowledge-base --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`2019-05-21T14:38:07.000Z`].{Key : Key, LastModified: LastModified }'

[
    {
        "Key": "images/tnats/connectivity.JPG",
        "LastModified": "2019-05-21T14:38:07.000Z"
    },
    {
        "Key": "images/tnats/gsk-logo.png",
        "LastModified": "2019-05-29T16:58:46.000Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Is there a speed benefit to doing this? Would this still list all objects in the bucket and then filter on the client side using `--query` ?